# Publish Web Api (MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I built a REST API following [this tutorial](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/3/creating_a_rest_service_using_asp_net_web_api) and [this one](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api), and when I run application from Visual Studio 2012 things seem to work properly.

The problem is when I publish (to file system), I get a new folder under wwwroot and some files are placed there, but when I try to access `http://localhost:82/my_published_api/` I only see a list of what seems useless files, `http://localhost:82/my_published_api/api/` throws a 404 as does `http://localhost:82/my_published_api/api/contact/` which is actually working from VStudio.

Am I missing something? What do I need to publish to a directory and access api modules?

**EDIT** some extra info:

This is `system.web` section in `Web.Config`:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

And pre-production published version is running in `http://localhost:82/my_published_api/` (this is the one which throws 404) while Visual Studio runtime server runs in `http://localhost:51976/api/contact/` (this one runs properly)

Pre-production site is IIS under Windows 7, real production site will be a Windows server 2003.

Thank you

Comment: ` I only see a list of what seems useless files` <-- what files ? Also, `my_published_api` .. is that a custom route? it would normally be (out of the box) simply `domain.com/api/contact`

Comment: `bin (dir) / packages.config / PrecompiledApp.config / Web.config`. I don't have a `domain.com` but a `localhost` which has a few folders (sites) working, it's a development environment, there are not custom routes as far as I know

Comment: Are you hosting this in IIS? I'm guessing IIS doesnt realise your appllication is using routing. Make sure your webconfig is referencing system.web.mvc and system.web.routing. You could always create a blank mvc application and compare the configs

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Are both your Visual Studio and IIS running in the same ports (i.e. 82)? This is not possible. If this is just a typo mistake and if you are hosting on a different server, you might need to install asp .net MVC on the server or publish all the files related to mvc by choosing copy local=true in visual studio..

Comment: @heymega , that makes sense but system.web.mvc and system.web.routing are present in Web.Config as you can see

Comment: @Muthu, no, published site is running on port 82, Visual Studio developmente web server is on port 51976, added more info on original question

Comment: @K.Weber Another thing to try...Make sure your application pool is targeting the right .net version.

Comment: Are you using a virgin IIS website (nothing else in the directory) or trying to run this as a sub-application?

Comment: @K.Weber, Is this IIS site configured as a virtual directory or is it a subfolder under a main site?

Comment: Did you install aspnet on iis?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configure-an-asp-net-website-on-iis

Comment: Application Pool is targeting correct .NET version, it's not a virgin website, it's a website which runs other classic asp and .net applications, which are all in subfolders under same server (and run as Applications not websites)

Comment: @Tascalator, thanks for the link, will see if there's something about routing. Other .NET apps are already running in this IIS